# Play sound with html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically what I need to do is to play a sound in the background.

The site has been designed full of html5 so I'm guessing that using the audio tag will be ok. These are mp3 files.

The problem and reason why I am asking here is that I need to find a way to know when the file is fully loaded (ready to play). These are short clips, about 10 secs.

Pretty much how can u do with images using like `img.onLoad=`

Comment: Check the "related" sidebar. Lots of ideas there.

Comment: If you're using the `<audio>` tag, have you tried `audio.onLoad`?

Comment: Hi Ron, it's general practice on SO to post code of what you've tried in your questions. This will help folks help you. Check out the [FAQ] for more info.

Comment: I eventually (sort of) understood what you're asking, but the wording and title of this question need a lot of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"fully loaded" and "ready to play" are two different things.

To explain: `<audio>` and `<video>` elements have three events for loading:

- `oncanplay` fires when enough of the media has loaded to at least start playing (usually the first couple of seconds)
- `oncanplaythrough` fires when enough has buffered for it to be able to play all the way through, finishing the buffering process along the way without it having to stop
- `onload` fires when the media has completely loaded.

It should be noted, though, that `oncanplay` is not widely supported. `onload` is the only reliable one, and it should be fine for such a short clip, but for a song or the like it is less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for que quick reaply. Will accept it once i can. (kinda ashamed to know that onload also works for audio.....) My mistake. Thanks again!